# If statements and strings

Tags: python-2.7

How can I get my code to respond to string inputs? I want it to do something if the answer is yes or no. I tried something like this.

```
yes = 'yes'
yesOrNo = input('yes or no?')
if yesOrNo == yes:
    print'you said yes'
```

No matter what I typed for the input, it always would say,'you said yes'.

Comment: If I enter 'no' in the input it doesn't print anything for me. If I enter no it throws an exception that "NameError: name 'no' is not defined".

Your snippet should work. Is there other code before or after this that could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2 `input` doesn't return a string, but an object. To do something like this you would want

```
choice = raw_input('yes or no?\n')
if choice == 'yes':
    print 'you said yes'
else:
    print 'you said no'
```

`raw_input` does return a string.